# Select follower tag, selectSingleNode in msxml

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing, xmldocument, msxml

How can I select the `MEDIUM` from that xml with VBScript Msxml?

```
<reference_list>
    <reference_tag>VAT</reference_tag>
    <reference_value>123</reference_value>
</reference_list>
<reference_list>
    <reference_tag>PRIORITY</reference_tag>
    <reference_value>MEDIUM</reference_value>
</reference_list>
```

I currently selected the PRIORITY tag, but i want to the follower reference_value's value MEDIUM:

```
xmlDoc.selectNodes("//insert_shipment/reference_list[reference_tag ='PRIORITY']")
```

Looping is not an option now, I have to select just that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure tzhat there is just **one** target node, use .selectSingleNode - as in:

```
  Dim objXML : Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  objXML.async = false
  objXML.load "../data/24607195.xml"

  If objXML.parseError Then ' never without my check
     WScript.Echo objXML.parseError.reason
  Else
     'Find single reference_value MEDIUM
     Dim sXPath : sXPath = "/insert_shipment/reference_list/reference_value[. = 'MEDIUM']"
     Dim ndMedium : Set ndMedium = objXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
     If ndMedium Is Nothing Then ' never without my check
        WScript.Echo "fail:", sXPath
     Else
        WScript.Echo ndMedium.parentNode.firstChild.text, ndMedium.xml
     End If
  End If
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I want ;)